# tkinter has select start on first element to be able to control with arrows keys only

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have the following code which opens up a GUI and fills the table:

# THE ITEMS INSERTED WITH A LOOP

```
for item in filtered_content:
    usb_box.insert(Tk.END, item)
usb_box.select_set(0)
gui.mainloop()
```

The problem, is that when the GUI starts, I can't move the select with the arrow keys only. I have to first select the first item (even though it's highlighted) then I can move my selection through the arrow keys. How can I have it select the first element by default so I can move my selection with only the arrows keys without needing to select the first element with my mouse?

Comment: `usb_box.focus_set()`, perhaps?  Having an item selected doesn't mean that it's the widget that has keyboard focus.

Comment: It worked! thank you